# Android - Draw Text At The Bottom Of A Bitmap Using Static Layout

Tags: android, text, bitmap, android-bitmap, staticlayout

I have the following code that puts some text at the top of an image:

```
    val paint = TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    paint.color = Color.WHITE
    paint.textSize = 40f //* context.resources.displayMetrics.density
    paint.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
    //paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.
    paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.DKGRAY)

    val teststr = "Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World"

    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    val textLayout = StaticLayout(teststr, paint, canvas.width ,Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1f, 0f, false)
    textLayout.draw(canvas)
```

However, in reality, I want the text to be at the bottom of the image. How can I align the `StaticLayout` with the bottom of the `Bitmap`, so the text appears at the bottom of the image.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `Canvas#translate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be the correct answer. Subtract the height of the `StaticLayout` from the height of the canvas.

```
    val paint = TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    paint.color = Color.WHITE
    paint.textSize = 40f //* context.resources.displayMetrics.density
    paint.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
    //paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.
    paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.DKGRAY)

    val teststr = "Hello World"

    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

    val textLayout = StaticLayout(teststr, paint, canvas.width ,Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1f, 0f, false)
    canvas.save()
    canvas.translate(0f,canvas.height - textLayout.height - 0.0f)
    textLayout.draw(canvas)
    canvas.restore()
```

Comment: Hi!, It's an excellent answer but just facing an issue of margin/padding between image and text. How I can give some space between image and Text without clipping, Thanks in advance.